# How do I fix ConnectionClosedError in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-textract

I am trying to call AWS textract using Python in Juptyer Notebooks. I want to extract tables from 5 pages. When I try I get a ConnectionClosedError. I think this is due to slow internet. It did work fine when I only wanted to extract from 1 page. How do I fix this? Doing some researching, I did find --cli-connect-timeout 6000 works for some people to increase the amount of time before it times out. I'm not sure how to run this command in Juptyer Notebooks. I am a Python and AWS beginner.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
call_textract(input_document="out"+str(i)+".png", features=[Textract_Features.TABLES])
```

This is the error I receive:

```
`timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    391         else:
--> 392             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    393 

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1239         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1240         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1241 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
     93             self.response_class = self._original_response_cls
---> 94         rval = super()._send_request(
     95             method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1285             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1286         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1287 

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1234             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1235         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1236 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py in _send_output(self, message_body, *args, **kwargs)
    122             message_body = None
--> 123         self.send(msg)
    124         if self._expect_header_set:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py in send(self, str)
    217             return
--> 218         return super().send(str)
    219 

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    966         try:
--> 967             self.sock.sendall(data)
    968         except TypeError:

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in sendall(self, data, flags)
   1203                 while count < amount:
-> 1204                     v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
   1205                     count += v

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in send(self, data, flags)
   1172                     self.__class__)
-> 1173             return self._sslobj.write(data)
   1174         else:

timeout: The write operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py in send(self, request)
    454             request_target = self._get_request_target(request.url, proxy_url)
--> 455             urllib_response = conn.urlopen(
    456                 method=request.method,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    723 
--> 724             retries = retries.increment(
    725                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    378             # Disabled, indicate to re-raise the error.
--> 379             raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    380 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    733             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 734                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    735             raise value

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    391         else:
--> 392             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    393 

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1239         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1240         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1241 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
     93             self.response_class = self._original_response_cls
---> 94         rval = super()._send_request(
     95             method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1285             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1286         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1287 

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1234             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1235         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1236 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py in _send_output(self, message_body, *args, **kwargs)
    122             message_body = None
--> 123         self.send(msg)
    124         if self._expect_header_set:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py in send(self, str)
    217             return
--> 218         return super().send(str)
    219 

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    966         try:
--> 967             self.sock.sendall(data)
    968         except TypeError:

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in sendall(self, data, flags)
   1203                 while count < amount:
-> 1204                     v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
   1205                     count += v

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in send(self, data, flags)
   1172                     self.__class__)
-> 1173             return self._sslobj.write(data)
   1174         else:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionClosedError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6ead0a7703a6> in <module>
----> 1 df1=extract_data("scan0995")
      2 # df1.to_pickle("df.pkl")
      3 # df1=breeding_clean(pd.read_pickle("df1.pkl"))
      4 # print(df1.to_string())

<ipython-input-2-af8fecab9b9f> in extract_data(input_document)
      5     for i, page in enumerate(pages):
      6         page.save("out"+str(i)+".png","PNG")
----> 7         resp = call_textract(input_document="out"+str(i)+".png", features=[Textract_Features.TABLES])
      8         tdoc = Document(resp)
      9         dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(convert_table_to_list(trp_table=tdoc.pages[0].tables[0])))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textractcaller\t_call.py in call_textract(input_document, features, queries_config, output_config, kms_key_id, job_tag, notification_channel, client_request_token, return_job_id, force_async_api, call_mode, boto3_textract_client, job_done_polling_interval)
    545 
    546                     if features:
--> 547                         result_value = textract.analyze_document(**params)
    548                     else:
    549                         result_value = textract.detect_document_text(**params)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528                 )
    529             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    531 
    532         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    941         else:
    942             apply_request_checksum(request_dict)
--> 943             http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
    944                 operation_model, request_dict, request_context
    945             )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _make_request(self, operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
    964     def _make_request(self, operation_model, request_dict, request_context):
    965         try:
--> 966             return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
    967         except Exception as e:
    968             self.meta.events.emit(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py in make_request(self, operation_model, request_dict)
    117             request_dict,
    118         )
--> 119         return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
    120 
    121     def create_request(self, params, operation_model=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py in _send_request(self, request_dict, operation_model)
    200             request, operation_model, context
    201         )
--> 202         while self._needs_retry(
    203             attempts,
    204             operation_model,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py in _needs_retry(self, attempts, operation_model, request_dict, response, caught_exception)
    352         service_id = operation_model.service_model.service_id.hyphenize()
    353         event_name = f"needs-retry.{service_id}.{operation_model.name}"
--> 354         responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
    355             event_name,
    356             response=response,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py in emit(self, event_name, **kwargs)
    410     def emit(self, event_name, **kwargs):
    411         aliased_event_name = self._alias_event_name(event_name)
--> 412         return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
    413 
    414     def emit_until_response(self, event_name, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py in emit(self, event_name, **kwargs)
    254                  handlers.
    255         """
--> 256         return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
    257 
    258     def emit_until_response(self, event_name, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py in _emit(self, event_name, kwargs, stop_on_response)
    237         for handler in handlers_to_call:
    238             logger.debug('Event %s: calling handler %s', event_name, handler)
--> 239             response = handler(**kwargs)
    240             responses.append((handler, response))
    241             if stop_on_response and response is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py in __call__(self, attempts, response, caught_exception, **kwargs)
    205             checker_kwargs.update({'retries_context': retries_context})
    206 
--> 207         if self._checker(**checker_kwargs):
    208             result = self._action(attempts=attempts)
    209             logger.debug("Retry needed, action of: %s", result)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py in __call__(self, attempt_number, response, caught_exception, retries_context)
    282             )
    283 
--> 284         should_retry = self._should_retry(
    285             attempt_number, response, caught_exception
    286         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py in _should_retry(self, attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
    318             # If we've exceeded the max attempts we just let the exception
    319             # propogate if one has occurred.
--> 320             return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
    321 
    322 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py in __call__(self, attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
    361     def __call__(self, attempt_number, response, caught_exception):
    362         for checker in self._checkers:
--> 363             checker_response = checker(
    364                 attempt_number, response, caught_exception
    365             )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py in __call__(self, attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
    245             return self._check_response(attempt_number, response)
    246         elif caught_exception is not None:
--> 247             return self._check_caught_exception(
    248                 attempt_number, caught_exception
    249             )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py in _check_caught_exception(self, attempt_number, caught_exception)
    414         # the MaxAttemptsDecorator is not interested in retrying the exception
    415         # then this exception just propogates out past the retry code.
--> 416         raise caught_exception

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py in _do_get_response(self, request, operation_model, context)
    279             http_response = first_non_none_response(responses)
    280             if http_response is None:
--> 281                 http_response = self._send(request)
    282         except HTTPClientError as e:
    283             return (None, e)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py in _send(self, request)
    375 
    376     def _send(self, request):
--> 377         return self.http_session.send(request)
    378 
    379 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py in send(self, request)
    492             raise ReadTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
    493         except ProtocolError as e:
--> 494             raise ConnectionClosedError(
    495                 error=e, request=request, endpoint_url=request.url
    496             )

ConnectionClosedError: Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "https://textract.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/".`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [pass in your own boto3 client](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-textractor/blob/master/caller/textractcaller/t_call.py#L429), on which you can [set the timeout](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html) in a `Config` object:

```py
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

client = boto3.client("textract", config=Config(connect_timeout=600))
```

Then you can call textract with you custom client:

```
call_textract(input_document="out"+str(i)+".png", features=[Textract_Features.TABLES], boto3_textract_client=client)
```